# How will summing a sub array affect time complexity in a nested for loop?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

Trying to calculate time complexity of some simple code but I do not know how to calculate time complexity while summing a sub array. The code is as follows:

```
for i=1 to n {
   for j = i+1 to n {
       s = sum(A[i...j])
       B[i,j]=s
}}
```

So I know the nested for loops inevitably give us a O(n^2) and I believe the function to sum to the sub array is also O(n^2). However, I think the time complexity for the whole algorithm is O(n^3). How do I get here with this information? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning leads me to believe that you're running this algorithm on a array of size n. If so, then every time you call the `sum` method in the inner for loop, you're calling this method on a specific range of values (indices i to j). For each iteration of this for loop, this `sum` method will iterate through 1, 2, 3, ..., then finally n elements in the last iteration as j increases from (i + 1) to n. Note that this is when i = 1. As i increases, it won't necessarily go from 1, 2, 3, ..., to n anymore since it will technically go up to n - i elements. Big O, though, is the worst case so we have to use this scenario.

1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n gives us n^2. The runtime of the `sum` method depends on the values of i and j; however, when run in the for loop with the given conditions, the total time-complexity of all the calls to `sum` in one iteration of the inner for loop is O(n^2). And finally, since this inner for loop is executed n times, the total time-complexity for the whole algorithm is O(n^3).

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of for loops as summations. As such, the number of steps (written as a function, `T(n)`) is:

```
T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n numStepsInInnerForLoop
```

Here, I'm using something written in pseudo-MathJax, and have written the outer for loop as a summation from `i=1` to `n` of the number of steps in the inner for loop (the one from `i+1` to `n`). You can think of this analagously as summing the number of steps in the inner for loop, from `i=1` to `n`. Substituting in `numStepsInInnerForLoop` results in:

```
T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n [\sum_{j=i+1}^n numStepsOfSumFunction]
```

This function now represents the number of steps where both for loops have been fleshed out as summations. Assuming that `s = sum(A[i...j])` takes `j-i+1` steps and `B[i,j]=s` takes just one step, we can substitute `numStepsOfSumFunction` with these more useful parameters and the equation now becomes:

```
T(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n [\sum_{j=i+1}^n (j-i+1 + 1)]
```

When you solve these summations (using the kind of formulas you see on [this summation tutorial page](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/SummationNotation.aspx)) you'll get a cubic function for `T(n)` which corresponds to `O(n^3)`.

Comment: [Indeed.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(sum(j+-+i+%2B+1+%2B+1),++j%3Di%2B1+to+n),+i%3D1+to+n)

Comment: Oh cool! Thanks @Abion47! I haven't seen this tool before. I didn't want to write out all that in MathJax code here but this is brilliant for similar problems in the future. :-D